# react - setting input prop based on input name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a checkbox input:

```
import { Checkbox } from 'semantic-ui-react';

<Checkbox
   checked={false}
   ref={id}
/>
```

Now I would like to write a function that set this checkbox's checked to true (the onClick function goes on another React element, not the checkbox itself):

```
onClick: (id) => {
    //Find the correct checkbox, set the prop
    this.refs[id].checked = true;
}
```

But I have no idea how to do it (the above code does nothing). How do I find react components based on a certain prop?

Comment: Post the complete code, `Checkbox` is component ? how you are creating it ?

Comment: Checkbox is a component from react-semantic-ui. The onClick function goes on a row in a table I am creating with another library, but they are both in the same component.

Comment: are you getting the id in onClick function ?

Comment: Yes, the id is pased to the function, sorry if that was unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain a state object that has mapping of id to checkbox state and then onClick based on the id change the state

```
this.state = {
     checked: {'12': true. '23':false}
}

<Checkbox
checked={this.state.checked[id]}
/>
```

If you want to toggle

```
    onClick = (id) => {
        var checked = {...this.state.checked}
        checked[id] = !this.state.checked[id];
        this.setState({checked})
    }
```

If you only want to set

```
    onClick = (id) => {
        var checked = {...this.state.checked}
        checked[id] = true;
        this.setState({checked})
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an onClick  attribute in the Checkbox and the funciton name.

Inside the on click function you should get as parameter the event
and check the evet.target.checked 
which is the checkbox's attribute to show clicked status.

You don't need to use refs if its all in the same component.

Let me know if you have trouble

Comment: Edited the question, I would like to add the onClick event on a div containing the checkbox, and not the actual checkbox - also there are a lot of checkboxes, that's why I was thinking of using refs

Comment: You can put the onclick in the parent-div  of the input-checkbox and the event.target will still seelct the checkbox I think. or you can selecti it like this 
if it show the parent event.target.querySelector("input")

Comment: but the other answers do it well too

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
<Checkbox
   checked={false}
   ref={id}
   onClick={() => { this.onClick(id); }}
/>
```

Not sure if this Checkbox is rendered in the same component tho, so the reference to `this` might be wrong.

```
onClick: (id) => {
    this.refs[id].checked = true;
}
```